# Will flying potentially damage my ears further?

Tags: ear, inner-ear, barotrauma, air-pressure, ear-canal

### Some Context...

A couple years ago my friend shouted into my ear very loud at a concert (stupid move, but I guess he just wasn't thinking), and ever since, it has been prone to getting blocked and is more sensitive to loud noises.

I have a number of flights in a row to complete tomorrow. I am flying from Australia to Brazil. I had a short flight, about `50 minutes` across states today (`Melbourne to Adelaide`)

**Tomorrow I'll be going from:**

`1. Adelaide to Dubai`

then

`2. Dubai to Rio De Janeiro`

over 23 hours or so.

### The Problem

While coming down to land on my flight today I started feeling quite a lot of pain and swelling in my ear canals. When I massaged between the behinds my ears to just underneath the joint of my jaw, I felt that the tube was so swollen that it had become rock hard.

Ever since the flight - about 3 hours from writing this, my ear on the right side (the one that was shouted into) is completely blocked, and there is a tight sensation in my sinuses, on that side of my face and I am experiencing mild nausea.

I will be trying to book an emergency appointment to see a GP today, but if they can't book me in, I'll have to take the advice of medical stack exchange and make a decision whether or not to fly further, for risk of damaging my ears.

### My Question

**Is it safe for me to fly today? Is there any chance that flying will injure me further?**

Comment: Unfortunately, personalised medical advice is off-topic! First paragraph is likely unrelated to your issues. Read up on [Eustachian tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustachian_tube), cabin pressure and compare. Might be just discomfort related to air pressure or serious issue of who knows what. We cannot answer that!